# Plot polynomial regression line

Tags: machine-learning

We got an assignment to run polynomial regression on a given data set (an excel file that contains 2 columns with the same size, one for x and one for y).
I tried to do it like this:

```
df_full = pd.read_excel(r'lab_test.xlsx', sheet_name='tests')
x_train_full = df_full.loc[:, 'test(mg)'].values
y_train_full = df_full.loc[:, 'chance %'].values

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
x_poly = poly.fit_transform(x_train_full.reshape(-1, 1))

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_poly, y_train_full)

y_prediction = model.predict(x_poly)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.scatter(x, y, label='original data')
plt.plot(x, hx, 'r', label='regression line')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

The problem is that the plot doesn't draw a polynomial line, but a line that goes back and forth, like this:
[image]

So my question is, what am I doing wrong? How to plot the line as it should be?
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you  should increase the `degree` value!

Comment: I tried that and it gt worse

Comment: Sort it by x value? Does it look okay if you use a scatter plot and no line connection?

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provided any data I used some randomly generated data points.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

samples = 50
np.random.seed(2020)

x = np.linspace(0.0,1.0,samples) 
r = np.random.rand(samples)    
y = np.array(list(map(lambda t: (t[0]**2) + t[1]/2, zip(x,r))))
X = x.reshape(-1,1) 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state = 0)
X_features = np.array([np.power(x,range(1,10)) for x in X_train])

pf = PolynomialFeatures(degree=9,include_bias=False)
X_features = pf.fit_transform(X_train)

model = LinearRegression().fit(X_features, y_train)

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10, 8]
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 100
plt.scatter(X_train,y_train,label='Training data')
plt.scatter(X_test,y_test,label='Test data')
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("y")

plt.plot(X, model.predict(pf.fit_transform(X)), color='red')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]